# One record, multiple updates in one query (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I run into a problem for which I didn't find an answer anywhere: If I have a table in which one specific value(here amount) from multiple records can add into a target record(from the same table), can I do it in a single query? This query below works, just that it only works for the first match(?!).

```
UPDATE test AS t1
LEFT JOIN test AS t2 ON t1.target = t2.obj_id
SET t2.amount = t2.amount + t1.amount, t1.amount = 0
WHERE t1.amount > 0 AND strcmp(t1.target, "null") <> 0;
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected result after the update.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something here, but maybe it only works for the first match because it sets `t1.amount = 0`, which means that record is excluded from a repeated invocation of the same command (whose `WHERE` clause requires `t1.amount > 0`)?

Comment: If I have 2 records that have the same target, when I reset the value of one of these(t1.amount = 0), it should not influence the second record, so when the second gets added to the target record, the target should have the sum of the two records. I just get the first record's value in the target, the rest are set to 0.